Display amount of features in SolidWorks with similar names in Excel using vba
I want to communicate information between SolidWorks and Excel using vba back and forth. I managed
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim myLength As Object
Dim BossExtrude As Object


'MAIN FUNCTION

Sub SolidworksToExcel()
    'Access active Solidworks and Excel files
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set xlsh = xl.ActiveSheet

    'Determine length
    Set myLength = Part.Parameter("D1@Distance3@Mold_Assembly.SLDASM")

    'Send to specific cell in Excel
    xlsh.Cells(6, 4).Value = myLength.SystemValue * 1000

End Sub

This code prints a set distance in cell (6,4).
Now, I want to print the amount of a features with the similar name in my assembly in a certain cell. For example in cell (7,4).
A part of my Solidworks feature tree looks like the following:

I want to know the amount of unsuppressed features that start with "Ejector Large [10mm]", even though they are not exactly within the same folder. To be clear, based on the image, it should display "2" in my excel, as there are two unsuppressed Ejector features in my image.
Can someone give me advice on how to accomplish this? Please do not hesitate to ask questions if anything is unclear.
Thank you in advance.

You can loop throug the feature tree, and make that counting.  Here you find an example on to do the loop and get the features names. You can use the IsSuppressed2 property to get the feature supression state. Example here

Thank you for your comment @solidWorking. The code works, but it only seems to print the folders and their names and not so much the actual features inside them. I am mainly interested in the features within folder Fixed and Moving: link
The screenshot of the features in my post are placed within the Fixed folder. Can you give me some advise on how to include that as well?

It looks that you are running this code in an assembly context, right? If that's the case guess you will need to traverse the assembly at component level and then loop throug the components features. Example code here

By the way, the Fixed Side and the Moving Side in the picture you shared are not folders. Those are components of the assembly and refer to part files. FS Plates is a folder.

To be more specific, currently it only prints the components "Fixed side" and I'm interested in the features in this figure: link

@solidWorking the new codes give indeed additional information, but still not the ones I am looking for. See my last link. It does not show "Ejector Large" anywhere.

Without the code and the models its hard to guess wath is going on. From the picture I see that one of Ejector Large features is supressed... How are you managing supressed features? Have you tried to run the code with all Ejector Large features unsupressed? Are those the only features that are missing??

Go through all the features and count the "Ejector Large [10mm]", Insert the following code in the loop that traverses the feature:
If InStr(featureName, "Ejector Large [10mm]") = 1 Then
            count = count + 1
        End If

